# How to return data as JSON in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

When I make a Sequelize query it returns to me an object (or array) which I'm guessing is a Sequelize model (or array of Models (a collection type??)) but it's not documented anywhere, so I'm just guessing. I would always like the results to be JSON. Is there anything I can pass in the query to force this? I would prefer not to hand massage every result I get back to be JSON if possible.

[The documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models/) show this to return a string:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(users))
```

So there's some built in serialization. Right now I'm doing this, using the undocumented `toJSON()` method:

```
query().then(function(result) {
    if(result.length) {
        return result.toJSON();
    } else {
        return result.map(function(item) {
            return item.toJSON();
        });
    }
});
```

which is cumbersome.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `raw: true` in the Query however this does not always behave as you might expect, especially with associations.

```
query({
    // ...
    raw: true
}).then(function(result) {
    // Result is JSON!
});
```

However in the case where you're using associations you may get something like this:

```
{
    foo: true,
    "associated.bar": true
}
```

Instead of what you might expect:

```
{
    foo: true,
    associated: {
        bar: true
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect answer.

Answer (score 11):

When you retrieve the model from the database, you can call the `.get({ plain: true})` on the result, which will handle the conversion for you. You can assign the value of the function call to a variable. For example

```
..).then(function(user){
     var _user = user.get({ plain: true});
     console.log(_user); //Should be valid json object
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing a query with which has multiple results you should expect an array to be returned. You should find that each element in the result array is a JSON object.

You should be able to access a given field like this: `result[0].myfieldname`

Comment: Does that mean it's impossible to force Sequelize to always return results as JSON?

Comment: It means they should already be in JSON. Try using JSON.stringify() to see what's inside. Your code should look something like this:

     `query().then(function(result) {
         console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
     });`